# Does a post-graduate certificate vs. a diploma make a difference when looking for a job in Canada?

Tags: canada, students

I'm from South Korea, and thinking about getting into a college in Canada.
I already have a bachelor's degree in Computer Science.

As I want to get a job in IT industry in Canada, I'd like to get a permanent residence in Canada at first.  When it comes to get the permanent residency in Canada, I heard I should get into the college and get 3 year's work permit, and get a full-time job.

I've been surfing the web for the last 2 weeks, and then I've found two kinds of college courses.

1. (2 Year) Post graduate certificate program (Co-op)
2. (3 Year) Diploma program (Co-op)

To get into the first one, I should prove that I've had a bachelor degree or diploma in the similar major, and some agency staff said that it will be better for you to get into the post graduate certificate program, because the post graduate certificate is higher than diploma degree.

He said,

**'Diploma < Advanced Diploma < Bachelor < Post Graduate Certification < Master'**

But I was wondering if it is true in Canada or not. He usually makes some money from someone like me, so to be honest, I couldn't trust what he said.

**Is there anyone who knows if it is true?**

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE.  I am not sure I follow what you're asking.  Are you asking of the Post Graduate courses help you in getting a Job?  Or are you asking if the academic structure is as some agency described to you?  Also if you're looking to get Permanent Residency outside of marriage I don't see a way of you getting it without a job, so can you clarify your intended sequence of events as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not necessary to have a job to have your permanent residency accepted. I didn't have one, and was accepted.

Answer (score 3):

In Canada, colleges are more known for education than Universities, and as you have your bachelor's degree in computer science, it is first stepping stone for Post Graduate Certificate program (2 Years) because you already have earned your bachelor's degree.

wasting 3 years in diploma program will be not worth it. I have spent my time in Canada as an international student that's why I can say if you have bachelor's degree you can choose any program with co-op option for job assistance from school.

For Permanent Residency, different Providences have different requirements but in Toronto, Ontario its worth checking www.centennialcollege.ca, www.senecacollege.ca, and www.humber.ca for college options. I am a graduate of centennial college and most of them offer 1 year post graduate diploma courses as well but withour co-op option. Please check their courses and contact international student department.

They will guide you for direct admissions and/or their authorized agents for your country for admissions help.

Hope, this information will help you